# CSS/JQuery Advice: Display hover over link and toggle div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a link (horizontal nav bar item) and when the user hovers over it another `div` should `slideDown` just below. `.toggle` doesn't work as it continuously toggles the div when you are hovering over the link.

I tried to write my own using `mouseover` and `mouseOut` but it's too sensitive and the `div` flips back and forth between displays (block, none).

Here's my jQuery:

```
    $(".topHorzNavLink").mouseover(function() {

    //get which link we hovered over
    var thisHorzLink = $(this).attr('linkItem');

    if (thisHorzLink == "link2") {

        $("#hoverContainer").slideDown('slow');

    }

});

$(".topHorzNavLink").mouseout(function() {

    //get which link we hovered over
    var thisHorzLink = $(this).attr('linkItem');

    if (thisHorzLink == "link2") {

        $("#hoverContainer").slideUp('slow');

    }

});
```

Here's the HTML (I know, ugh, it will be dynamic at some point):

```
<nav id="topHorzNav">

            <div id="topHorzNavLinks">

                <ul>
                    <li><p class="topHorzNavLink" linkItem="link1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></p></li>
                    <li><p class="topHorzNavLink" linkItem="link2"><a href="#">Link 2</a></p>
                <div id="hoverContainer">
                    <div class="colContainer">
                        <div class="colContainer">
                            <div class="colContainer">
                                <div class="colContainer">
                                    <div class="colContainer">

                                        <!--col 1-->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p class="colHeader">Heading 1</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="colDivider">&nbsp;</div>

                                        <!--col2 -->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p class="colHeader">Heading 2</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="colDivider">&nbsp;</div>

                                        <!--col3 -->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p class="colHeader">Heading 3</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="colDivider">&nbsp;</div>

                                        <!--col4 -->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p class="colHeader">Heading 4</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="colDivider">&nbsp;</div>

                                        <!--col5 -->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p class="colHeader">Heading 5</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                            <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><p class="topHorzNavLink"><a href="#" class="topHorzNavLink" linkItem="link3">Link 3</a></p></li>
                    <li><p class="topHorzNavLink"><a href="#" class="topHorzNavLink" linkItem="link4">Link 4</a></p></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div id="topHorzNavRight">&nbsp;</div>

        </nav>
        <!--end top horz nav items-->
```

Comment: Can you please create in in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function to clear the queued animations otherwise every time you  move in and out of the `<li>` more animations will be triggered. The other problem is that you are using [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) which is triggering the animation *even when the pointer is inside the child elements*. `mouseout()` also creates events that bubble up when the pointer leaves child elements. You are better off using [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

Here is [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2KkQC/) using HTML5 and jQuery 1.7.2. I have to say your example is very verbose!

#### HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <div>
                <!--col 1-->
                <section>
                    <header><h1>Heading 1</h1></header>
                    <article>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <!--col2 -->
                <section>
                    <header><h1>Heading 2</h1></header>
                    <article>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <header><h1>Heading 3</h1></header>
                    <article>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <header><h1>Heading 4</h1></header>
                    <article>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <header><h1>Heading 4</h1></header>
                    <article>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                        <p class="colText">Lorem Ipsum Dolar</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    width:150px;
}
li {
    border:1px dashed lightgrey;
}
li > div {
    display:none;
}
h1 {
   font-size:14px;
}

​section {
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:1px dashed lightblue;
}
```

​​​

#### JavaScript

```
$('li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('div:first').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('div:first').stop(true, false).slideUp('slow');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function. It has two parameters, each one is a function. The first one is for the `mouseover` event, the second is for the `mouseout` event.

I tried the following code and it worked:

```
$(function() {  
$('#nav-list>li').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown(300);
}, function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
});
});
```

Comment: Copyright - really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552544/can-javascript-code-be-copyrighted. Also you answer does not work. No where in the OP question is an element with `#nav-list`